# Converter String em float no R

Tags: r

Olá, como faço para converter

```
b <- format(round(3, 2), nsmall = 2)
[1] "3.00"
```

Nisso

[1] 3.00

Já tentei utilizar as.numeric, as.double, mas sempre me retorna 3 porém preciso de 3.00

Comment: Por que precisa de 3.00 como um numérico? Por que "3.00" como string não atende?

Answer (score 3):

Creio que está a confundir o número e a saída do método `print` para objetos de classe `"numeric"`, que é o método `print.default`. O número que tem já é `3.00`.
Senão veja primeiro como está representado internamente pelo R.

A função `typeof`é descrita assim na documentação, `help("typeof")`.

> Description
>
> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

Tradução Google, editada por mim.

> Descrição
>
> typeof determina o tipo (interno R) ou o modo de armazenamento de qualquer objeto

```
typeof(3)
#[1] "double"
```

Ou seja, o número `3` corresponde ao `"double"` da linguagem C, que são números em vírgula flutuante com 64 bits.

Para chamar o método `print` correspondente a estes objetos é mais útil saber a classe do objeto.

```
class(3)
#[1] "numeric"
```

Como não existe um método `print.numeric` o R executa `print.default`. Pode ver o código com o comando

```
print.default
```

só assim, sem parêntesis.
Este método só printa o que for necessário, como só `print(3)` não precisa de mais casa decimais ele não as mostra.

Tente agora ver o resultado de

```
round(c(3, pi), 2)
#[1] 3.00 3.14
```

Para o resultado de `round(pi, 2)` o `print` precisa de duas decimais portanto isso é usado para *todo o vetor*.